# Button Freezes after webpage left idle for sometime

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, polling

I have one web application developed in Spring and JSF (Primefaces). I am using polling at this page.

```
  <p:poll listener="#{listenerMethod}" update="chekin"
        interval="2" />
```

Chekin is the content that is being polled.
It is working fine.
Inside polled content, there are dynamically generated buttons.

Those are working fine. But if you leave the that webpage idle for 5 10 minutes, the buttons will not work. It wont be clicked.

Do anyone have idea on this, what possible issue may be, how can it be resolved.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Whats your session timeout in web.xml?

Comment: seesion timeout is 10 seconds. But polling is always there at every 2 seconds. Even after 5 6 unsuccessful click, it might work too.

Comment: Check your console for any javascript errors.

Comment: No error, normally it is working fine. The issue I mentioned happening sometime..if the page would be left for 5 10 minutes without any activity